# If I have $A+B-C=\pi$ and want to evaluate $\sin^2(A)+\sin^2(B)-\sin^2(C)$, can I simply apply $\sin^2$ to the terms of the first equation?

Tags: trigonometry

I have an equation,
$$A+B-C=\pi$$
I am interested in finding
$$\sin^2(A)+\sin^2(B)-\sin^2(C)$$
So I thought of taking $\sin^2$ function on the terms of the given equation, but I want to know if it is legit in taking $\sin^2$ or $\sin$ functions on all the terms of an equation.

Answer (score 2):

If $A+B=C,$
then $\sin^2(A+B)=\sin^2(C)$ is correct, not $\sin^2A+\sin^2B=\sin^2C$.

Comment: LaTeX/MathJax have a symbol `\sin` which renders in an upright font with a proper spacing as a function symbol . Please use that instead of plain `sin`, which looks like a multiplication of three variables. Compare: `\sin x` → $\sin x$ vs. `sin x` → $sin x$.

Comment: @CiaPan Done.Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You may want also to see our [Help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help), section [Our model](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/stackexchange), topic [How can I format mathematics here?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and two further links given therein.

Answer (score 1):

It is not legitimate. Try it out for some values of the variables where you know the $\sin$.

In fact the operation "apply a function to every element of a sum to get the function applied to the sum" is hardly ever legitimate. It does not work for powers or roots or logarithms or exponentials. It does work for multiplication by a fixed number. Then it is called the distributive law.

Comment: The "plus one" function is probably a most striking counter-example :)  $a+b+c=d$ does _not_ imply $(a+1)+(b+1)+(c+1)=(d+1).$

Answer (score 1):

We have,

$\mathrm{A+B-C=\pi}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,...(1)$

Now,

$\mathrm{sin^{2}(A)+sin^{2}(B)-sin^{2}(C)}$

$\mathrm{=\dfrac{1-cos(2A)}{2}+\dfrac{1-cos(2B)}{2}-\dfrac{1-cos(2C)}{2}}$

$\mathrm{=\dfrac{1}{2}-\dfrac{cos(2A)}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2}-\dfrac{cos(2B)}{2}-\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{cos(2C)}{2}}$

$\mathrm{=\dfrac{1}{2}-\dfrac{cos(2A)}{2}-\dfrac{cos(2B)}{2}+\dfrac{cos(2C)}{2}}$

$\mathrm{=\dfrac{1}{2}-\dfrac{1}{2}\Big\{cos(2A)+cos(2B)-cos(2C)\Big\}}$

$\mathrm{=\dfrac{1}{2}-\dfrac{1}{2}\left\{2\,cos\left(\dfrac{2A+2B}{2}\right)\,cos\left(\dfrac{2A-2B}{2}\right)-2\,cos^{2}(C)+1\right\}}$

$\mathrm{=\dfrac{1}{2}-\dfrac{1}{2}\Big\{2\,cos(A+B)\,cos(A-B)-2\,cos^{2}(C)+1\Big\}}$

From (1), we get,

$\mathrm{=\dfrac{1}{2}-\dfrac{1}{2}\Big\{2\,cos(\pi+C)\,cos(A-B)-2\,cos^{2}(C)\Big\}-\dfrac{1}{2}}$

$\mathrm{=-\dfrac{1}{2}\Big\{-2\,cos(C)\,cos(A-B)-2\,cos^{2}(C)\Big\}}$

$\mathrm{=\dfrac{2\,cos(C)}{2}\Big\{cos(A-B)+cos(C)\Big\}}$

$\mathrm{=cos(C)\Big\{cos(A-B)+cos(A+B-\pi)\Big\}}$

$\mathrm{=cos(C)\Big\{cos(A-B)+cos(\pi-(A+B))\Big\}}$

$\mathrm{=cos(C)\Big\{cos(A-B)-cos(A+B)\Big\}}$

$\mathrm{=cos(C)\Big\{2\,sin(A)\,sin(B)\Big\}}$

$\mathrm{=2\,sin(A)\,sin(B)\,cos(C)}$